# How to list *args of multi-interface function in Google-style docstring?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx, variadic-functions, docstring

I have the following function, wondering how to correctly document its multiple interfaces:

```
def log(self, *args):
    """Logs data in-memory to a list container, associated with a unix-path-like key.

    Args:
        **either**
        vpath (str): Virtual path
        value (Any): Value to store
        **or**
        vpath_value_map (Dict[str, Any]): Mapping of vpaths and values to store

    Raises:
        TypeError -- Wrong number of arguments.
    """
    if not (0 < len(args) < 3):
        raise TypeError("Method has to be called with either one or two arguments.")
```

I'd like to stick to Google Style and ideally Sphinx should work with it.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: My suggestion is to simply add a clarifying paragraph to the docstring. Something like this: "The function takes either one (``vpath_value_map``) or two (``vpath`` and ``value``) positional arguments."